# Is there a way to connect to SQL server without OBDC driver in perl?

Tags: sql, sql-server, perl

Is there a way to connect to SQL server without OBDC driver in perl?

I need to run a script in a machine that i can not install drivers. The specific machine dont have OBDC driver, so I cant run the script

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:ODBC:Driver={SQL Server}"....
```

I searched on the web but I found nothing. Anyone can help me plz?

Comment: Unfortunately I cant, must be that server....

Comment: Last resort - powershell components or the old sqlcmd command-line tool. Not fun that way though.

Comment: Is it the ODBC driver for the database that you can't install, or the DBI driver for ODBC? If the latter, why can't you install it? It can be installed in any directory and should not need any special permissions.

Comment: What is preventing you from installing the required software on this box? I'd suggest that your time would be better spent removing that obstacle so that you can do the work with the recommended tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running windows, take a look this module:

http://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::ODBC

(First you need to define an ODBC connection in odbc administrator)

With this sample im able to connect:

```
my $Db="ODBC_CONN";
my $Db_Conex = new Win32::ODBC($Db); 

$Db_Conex->Sql("select bar from foo");
while ($Db_Conex->FetchRow()){
    my $FooValue =  $Db_Conex->Data();
}
```

Comment: Didn't the op say the odbc driver is not installed and he cannot install it? Your answer looks like another way to connect using ODBC

Comment: @harmic, I believe the Win32::ODBC module *is* the driver in this case. I think the ODBC infrastructure itself is always present.

Comment: Hum... I tested but it give me this error: `Can't locate DBD/ODBC.pm in @INC (@INC contains: D:/oracle/product/11.1.0/OraFusMid_WebTier/perl/lib D:/oracle/product/11.1.0/OraFusMid_WebTier/perl/site/lib .) at teste_DB.pl line 3. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at teste_DB.pl line 3.`

Comment: Dbd:odbc? My example is using win32:odbc. Could you post the code you are using?

Comment: First of all thanks for the help. Sorry, wrong error. The code I'm using is:
`my $dsn = ("$dsn;Server=$host;Database=$bd");
my $Db_Conex = new Win32::ODBC("$dsn;UID=$user;PWD=$auth"); `

And It gives-me this error:
`Can't locate win32/OCBD.pm in @INC (@INC...`

Comment: Another drive missing, but I'll put your question as the right one because It realy solves the problem of people who cant use the OCBD driver